# How to mock nested static methods using PowerMockito?

Tags: java, methods, static, mockito, powermockito

How can I mock nested static methods using PowerMockito?
The following is a very simple example on how I want to use it.

**Class:**

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static String someMethodA(){
        //some very important codes here
        return someMethodB();
    }
    private static String someMethodB(){
        return someMethodC();
    }
    private static String someMethodC(){
        return "Some Text";
    }
}
```

Already tried the following but did not work:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeClass.class);
PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(SomeClass.class, "someMethodB")).toReturn("Some Other Text");
```

I wanted to run someMethodA() as is, which is why I want to stub someMethodB() instead. Is there anyway I can do this? Hoping that there is a way without having to modify the access modifiers because the codes I am working with are legacy codes.

Comment: Hi Friend, Do you mean you want to unit test `someMethodA` which is private with mocking `someMethodB` ? Or Is that fine If `someMethodA` which is public too?.

Comment: Hi Praveen. Yes. Editted someMethodA to be public. It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can `spy` the private static methods.

**Tested in `JUnit4`**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        spy(SomeClass.class);
        when(SomeClass.class, "someMethodB").thenReturn("Some Other Text");
        assertEquals("Some Other Text", SomeClass.someMethodA());
    }

}
```